# Why doesn't gem install fpm via ansible?

Tags: amazon-ec2, ansible

I have created an EC2 instance on Amazon Cloud and I am installing some stuffs via ansible too. But when it installs fpm using gem:

```
- name: install fpm
  gem: name=fpm state=latest
  sudo: yes
```

it says:

```
changed: [XX.XX.XXX.XXX] => {"changed": true, "name": "fpm", "state": "latest", "version": "1.3.3"}
```

No errors. But when I enter the instance and try to run a script it says:

```
fpm is mandatory, please run gem install fpm
```

If I do `sudo gem install fpm` in console of the EC2, the script runs as espected.

So what am I doing wrong? Doesn't Ansible install the fpm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the problem by doing

```
- name: install fpm
  command: bash -lc "gem install fpm"
```

instead of

```
- name: install fpm
  gem: name=fpm state=latest
  sudo: yes
```

Now It does not ask for `fpm` anymore, it is installed. But why `gem` does not work?

Comment: That doesn't explain the original error...it's just a workaround

Comment: I know, and that is why I said "But why `gem` does not work?" at the end of the answer